# Display the results of an array on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to load an array from one page and then have the results appear on another using javascript/jQuery. So a user will make a selection from a dropdown. Based on this dropdown the "customers" address, phone, email, etc. will appear in a text field. I'm trying to store those results in to the array (name | address | etc in one index of the array), display the result on the second screen, and then allow the user to add more names if necessary.

At the moment I'm trying to use localStorage to store the values and then JSON.stringify to convert the results so they can be stored in the array.

I think these are all of the pertinent lines:

```
var customerArray = [];

var getName = $('#DropDownList1').val();
var getAddress = $('#DataList1').text().trim();
var getPhone = $('#DataList2').text().trim();
var getEmail = $('#DataList3').text().trim();
    //store the variables
localStorage.setItem("name", getName);
localStorage.setItem("address", getAddress);
localStorage.setItem("phone", getPhone);
localStorage.setItem("email", getEmail);
    //user will click #btnAdd to add the customers information
    //into customerArray[]
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    var setName = localStorage.getItem("name");
    var setAddress = localStorage.getItem("address");
    var setPhone = localStorage.getItem("phone");
    var setEmail = localStorage.getItem("email");

    var post = setName + setAddress + setPhone + setEmail;

    if (customerArray.length == 0) {
        customerArray[0] = post;
    } else {
        for (var i = 1; i < customerArray.length; ++i) {
            //store results of 'post' into the array
            customerArray.push(post); 
         localStorage.setItem("storedArray",JSON.stringify(customerArray));
        }
    }
}); //end #btnAdd click event
```

Form here the 2nd page will load with a text field that will (should) display the results of the array (customerArray). Unfortunately I can only get 1 value to appear.

At the moment this is the block being used to display the results:

```
  $('#tbContactList').val(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedArray")));
```

If it matters I'm writing the application using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. The data that initially populates the customers information comes from a database that I've used ASP controls to get. I'm confident there is a perfectly simple solution using ASP/C# but I'm trying to solve this problem using javascript/jQuery - I'm more familiar with those languages than I am with C#.

Thank you.

Comment: can you check what is saved in localstorage ? (Chrome)Open your console go to ressources on the left check localstorage.

Comment: You said: "Unfortunately I can only get 1 value to appear". What's the 1 value and what are you expecting?

Comment: I'm using Firebug in FF but on the first page the name, address, phone, and email and then the combined results (name + address + phone + email) are being stored in localStorage. So it appears everything from here is good.

Comment: When I click the button to navigate to the second page address, email and phone are null and name is undefined but the 'storedArray' still holds the combined value - what I want to display. 

When I try to add more names (which takes me back to the first page) all localStorage is reset.

The problem has something to do with the array value not being saved once it's displayed on the 2nd page.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.join() to turn your array into a string to store.
Then use Array.split() to turn your string back into an Array.

Example

```
var arr=['name','email','other'];
var localStorageString=arr.join(',');
localStorage.setItem('info',localStorageString);

var reassemble=localStorage.info.split(',');

for(var i=0;i<reassemble.length;i++){
    document.body.innerHTML+=reassemble[i]+"<br/>";   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5onLxd3/

Why does the user have to leave the current page though? IS a tabbed/dynamic interface not an option?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a requirement of the project.